# Remove mirrored objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an issue which I dont't really know how to tackle in a good way

I have an array of objects which looks roughly like this:

```js
[
    { name: "horse", newName: "owl" }
    { name: "owl", newName: "horse" }
    { name: "frog", newName: "dog" }
]
```

I want to remove "mirrored" objects from this array, in result having an array like this:

```js
[
    { name: "frog", newName: "dog" }
]
```

Basically I need to find objects with opposite keys and values

More complex scenarios:

```js
[
    { name: "horse", newName: "frog" }
    { name: "owl", newName: "horse" }
    { name: "frog", newName: "owl" }
]

    // Result: []
```

```js
[
    { name: "horse", newName: "frog" }
    { name: "dog", newName: "cat" }
    { name: "owl", newName: "horse" }
    { name: "frog", newName: "owl" }
    { name: "monkey", newName: "worm" }
    { name: "cat", newName: "dog" }
]

    // Result: [{ name: "monkey", newName: "worm" }]
```

In the first case I would simply loop through the array and if an object like this is found:

`{name: obj1.value2, newName: obj1.value1}` I would splice them both

But I have no idea how to approach the more complex situation when 3 or more objects would have to be removed. Any hints?

In advance thanks for your time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please may you add a [mcve] of that effort?

Comment: Objects keys are not ordered. At least, you should not rely on ordered keys when using objects. In practice, they are basically ordered, when using the v8 engine, but this isn't mandated by the spec. The spec says object keys are not ordered.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mirrored" objects? I would think that you mean the mirror of `{ name: "horse", newName: "frog" }` would be `{ name: "frog", newName: "horse" }`, but this doesn't appear in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some to check the present value.

```js
var array = [{
    name: "horse",
    newName: "frog"
  },
  {
    name: "dog",
    newName: "cat"
  },
  {
    name: "owl",
    newName: "horse"
  },
  {
    name: "frog",
    newName: "owl"
  },
  {
    name: "monkey",
    newName: "worm"
  },
  {
    name: "cat",
    newName: "dog"
  }
]

array.forEach(t => {

  var nameFound = array.some(a => a.name == t.newName);
  var newNameFound = array.some(a => a.newName == t.name);
  if (!nameFound && !newNameFound) {
    console.log(t);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using `filter` function on array

```js
var data = [
    { name: "horse", newName: "frog" },
    { name: "dog", newName: "cat" },
    { name: "owl", newName: "horse" },
    { name: "frog", newName: "owl" },
    { name: "monkey", newName: "worm" },
    { name: "cat", newName: "dog" }
];


let noMirrored = data.filter(one => {
  return (
    !data.some(element => element.name === one.newName) &&
    !data.some(element => element.newName === one.name)
  );
});

console.log(noMirrored);
```